# How to maintain the spaing between words?(HTML to text)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read a HTML file and  write the Unicode content to another file 
but the spacing between the  words is lost, In Html there are spaces

How to fix it ?

```
import codecs


def contains_nonascii(text):
    try:
        str(text).encode('ASCII')
        return False
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return True
```

This is the HTML file

http://www.mathrubhumi.com/index.php

```
''.join([text for text in texts if contains_nonascii(text)])

data =open("abc.html" ,'r' )
d2 = open("TETS2", 'w')
texts = data.read()
for text in texts:
    if contains_nonascii(text):
        text.replace(' ', ' ')
        d2.write(text)

data.close()
d2.close()
```

Comment: You could replace with ' '  with '&nbsp;'

Comment: @SparkyNo, It is not working

Comment: Could you show us a snippet of abc.html for which your program fails?

Comment: Are you sure the contains_nonascii() function is getting triggered?  Look in the abc.html to see if you have any &nbsp; characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code change...

```
 text.replace(' ', '&nbsp;')
```

is a non-breaking space in HTML

is told by browsers to display a space character.  If they are not appearing in your HTML file, then you either don't have any spaces of the function Contains_nonAscii() is not return true (hence the replace never occurs)

Try taking the replace out of the conditional...